# Get unique 3 digit zips from a list C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a list of integers that represent US ZIP codes, and I want to get unique values based on the first three digits of the ZIP code. For example this is my list:

```
10433
30549
10456
54933
60594
30569
30659
```

My result should contain only:

```
10433
30549
54933
60594
30659
```

The US ZIP codes excluded from my list are: **10456** and **30659** because I already have the ZIPs that contain 104xx and 306xx.

I really don't know how to get this done, I guess it's not that hard, but I have no idea. I've made a function, that saves me the unique first three digits, and I've added some random 2 digits at the end of each zip. But it didn't worked out because I got for example 10423 but 10423 is not in my list, and I don't have a specific pattern that all my numbers have the last 2 digits in a range.

Comment: You've tagged with regex. This looks like a problem better solved with linq. Is that allowed or is regex actually a requirement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little Linq should work. If using a list of `int`s:

```
var zips = new[] { 10433, 30549, 10456, 54933, 60594, 30569, 30659 };
var results = zips.GroupBy(z => z / 100).Select(g => g.First());
```

Or if using a list of `string`s:

```
var zips = new[] { "10433", "30549", "10456", "54933", "60594", "30569", "30659" };
var results = zips.GroupBy(z => z.Remove(3)).Select(g => g.First());
```

---

Another solution would be to use a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For `int`s:

```
class ZipComparer : IEqualityComparer<int> {
    public bool Equals(int x, int y) {
        return x / 100 == y / 100;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(int x) {
        return x / 100;
    }
}
```

For `string`s:

```
class ZipComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {
    public bool Equals(string x, string y) {
        return x.Remove(3) == y.Remove(3);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string x) {
        return x.Remove(3).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you can simply call `Distinct`:

```
var result = zips.Distinct(new ZipComparer());
```

---

Finally, you also use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `DistinctBy` extension method (also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)):

```
var results = zips.DistinctBy(z => z / 100);
// or
var results = zips.DistinctBy(z => z.Remove(3));
```

Comment: thanks man! you saved me a lot of time. I will accept the answer in few minutes, because I can't right now

Answer (score 2):

The popular answer here gives code, but doesn't solving the problem.  The problem is that you don't seem to have an algorithm.  So...

**How would you solve this problem on paper?**

I would imagine the process would be something like this:

1. For each number, determine the 3 digit prefix
2. If you don't already have a zip with that prefix, keep the number
3. If you do already have a zip with that prefix, discard the number

**How would you write this in code?**

Well, there's a couple things you need:

- A bucket to keep track of what prefixes you have found, and which values you've kept.
- A loop over all of the items
- A way to determine the prefix

Here's one way to write this (you can convert it to using strings instead as an exercise):

```
ICollection<int> GetUniqueZipcodes(int[] zips)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> bucket = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    foreach (var zip in zips)
    {
        int prefix = GetPrefix(zip);
        if(!bucket.ContainsKey(prefix))
        {
            bucket.Add(prefix, zip);
        }
    }
    return bucket.Values;
}

int GetPrefix(int zip)
{
    return zip / 100;
}
```

**Getting concise**

Now, many programmers these days would say "OMG so many lines of code this could be a one liner".  And they're right, it could.  Borrowing from p.s.w.g's answer, this can be condensed (in a very readable manner) to:

```
var results = zips.GroupBy(z => z / 100).Select(g => g.First());
```

So how does this work?  `zips.GroupBy(z => z/100)` does the bucketing operation.  You end up with a collection of groups that looks like this:

```
{ 
    104: { 10433, 10456 },
    305: { 30549, 30569 },
    549: { 54933 },
    605: { 60594 },
    306: { 30659 }
}
```

Then we use `.Select(g => g.First())`, which takes the first item from each group.